# How to Apply Month Filter To Table React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is My code I am using dropdown and values, for example, clicking on January the 1 value is sent to function and states updates and that month record is shown but after that when I will try to see another month's data then it not showing. and when click on default I want to all data as it was previously.
Thanks In Advance!

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  if (mon !== null || mon !== 0 || mon !== undefined) {
    const rows = prevState.rows.filter((element) => {
      return element.monthname === mon;
    });
    return {
      rows,
    };
  } else {
    const rows = prevState.rows.filter((element) => {
      return element.monthname !== null;
    });
    return {
      rows,
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a small stackblitz project to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @AhmerMH how I am using a database data

Comment: Just use some dummy inputs of 4-5 elements with correct data of date (or month) on which you actually want to sort. You don't need to add all columns, just 1-2 will be enough to replicate the problem.

Comment: Your `this.setState(...)` call looks fine; I'm guessing your problem exists outside of that. Can you share the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `prevState` :

keep `rowsOriginal` in the state alongside the `rows` :

```
this.state = {
     rows:[]
     rowsOriginal:[]
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetchRows().then(rows=>this.setState({rows:rows,rowsOriginal:rows})
}
```

then always filter from `rowsOriginal` and set status to `rows`:

```
this.setState({rows:rowsOriginal.filter((element) => {
      return element.monthname === mon;
})})
```

When setting default:

```
this.setState({rows:rowsOriginal})
```

So,

```js
if (mon !== null && mon !== 0 && mon !== undefined) {
    this.setState({rows:rowsOriginal.filter((element) => {
          return element.monthname === mon;
    })})
}
else {
    this.setState({rows:rowsOriginal})    
}
```

Comment: ```this.setState({rows:this.state.rowsOriginal.rows.filter((element) => {
      return element.monthname === mon;
})})``` is there this.state.rowsOriginal needed because its generating error.

Comment: this works halfway it does not return original rows when clicking on default i.e value 0.

Comment: also, there was a typo rowsOriginal.rows

Comment: instead of using ```||```, I used ```&&``` with your solution it's solved my issue the problem is with OR operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
this.state = { filteredRow: [] }

this.setState((prevState) => {
  if (mon) {
    const filteredRow = prevState.rows.filter((element) => {
      return element.monthname === mon;
    });
    return {
      filteredRow
    };
  } else {
    return {
      filteredRow: prevState.rows
    };
  }
});
```

Use a separate state varaible to maintain your filtered rows.

Else condition filter is not required as you can directly show all the records. `Filter` will unnecessary increase the compute by looping through data.

Comment: @ROHANTONGLE what is not working, can you be specific?

Comment: I have updated the answer. It should be `prevState.rows`